# How to install all the dependency package in yarn?

Tags: yarnpkg

First, I'm new to React. I'm trying to use Google's `Material-UI` for my React project. In [this tutorial](https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit-react/?_ga=2.235048965.509906277.1536193012-1441586403.1534889788#/documentation/tutorial), it says run `npm install`, but I heard using `yarn` and `npm` together in the same project because it might bring about some confusion between those two later. So, I'm trying to stick to `yarn` only.

`npm install` seems to install all the dependency package for the thing that I wanna use, but how can I do that in yarn? I tried `yarn add`, but it didn't work. How can I do that?

**EDIT**

Just found that it has only `package.json`, which means I can only use `npm install` to install dependencies. Would there be no problem when I use yarn later?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should just be able to run [`yarn`](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install) ("Running yarn with no command will run `yarn install`, passing through any provided flags." So just a simple `yarn` is what you'd want now, this answer previously suggested `yarn install`)

[Here is a comparison table](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/migrating-from-npm/#toc-cli-commands-comparison) of most/all the commands you'd likely encounter

---

Edit Sept 2020: The newer versions of `npm` have greatly improved and caught up to `yarn`, so I currently have no clue what possible benefits `yarn` offers anymore, I'm 100% `npm` for the last year or so

Comment: that link gives me a big help! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Thymine Yarn still edges out npm because it supports simultaneous package installs.

Comment: @robvelor That is a nice feature, although I'd always suggest using a local-network cached copy of packages as your main source, the time saved would be milliseconds difference with that infrastructure. If you're not inside a datacenter it would be more useful yes

Answer (score 6):

The equivalent of `$ npm install` is just `$ yarn` (without arguments) to install all dependencies from package.json.

Also, just to clarify your query -

> Just found that it has only package.json, which means I can only use npm install to install dependencies. Would there be no problem when I use yarn later?

Doesn't matter whether you use yarn or npm, there will always be a `package.json`.

And no, there won't be a problem when using yarn later.

You get `package-lock.json` when using npm, and `yarn.lock` file when using yarn.
It's not recommended to use both yarn and npm for the same project, so you should remove either of `package-lock.json` and `yarn.lock`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked as - yarn global add @angular/cli (similarly any dependency)
then added path "C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules.bin" in "Edit the system environment variables" -> Environment Variables -> Under System Variables select PATH-> click New -> Add the above path then save-> Open new command prompt -> run the dependency command.

Answer (score 0):

`yarn install --force`

From Yarn's help text on the `install` command:

> `--force`   install and build packages even if they were built before, overwrite lockfile

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation where `nom install` would install everything and `yarn install` wouldn't. So maybe try the other package manager?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore `NODE_ENV=PRODUCTION` and install all dependencies for your prod environment, use:

```
yarn install --production=false
```

> Yarn docs [here](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/install/#toc-yarn-install-production-true-false)

Answer (score 0):

Also, when you run `yarn install` (or `npm install`), the package manager resolves and installs the dependencies listed in the `package.json` file. It will create a `yarn.lock` file (or `package-lock.json` for npm) to track the installed dependencies and their versions.